# Django | Static Files not loading in Production even after executing Collect static

Tags: django

I have a django app on Linode and the static files are not loading. I have executed the collectstatic command and defined STATIC_ROOT as well.

I have used {%load static%} in my html file and using the following command to link the css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'mystyle.css' %}">
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Here is the photo of my file structure.

[image]

Comment: What webserver are you using in production to serve the static files (eg. nginx) ?

Comment: I have still not configured a webserver. Just did python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 and tried accessing with the IP. The html loads but not the css.

Comment: Is DEBUG in settings.py set to True or False?

Comment: It is set to True

Answer (score 1):

"python manage.py runserver" starts a webserver that is suitable for development only. You don't need to use collectstatic in a development environment. The Django development webserver will serve the CSS and other static files without collectstatic.

In a production environment, "python manage.py collectstatic" copies the static files (including CSS) to a directory that can then be served by a reverse proxy web server (eg. nginx). In production, you need an application server (eg. gunicorn) to serve the Django application. However you also need a reverse proxy web server (eg. nginx) to forward the relevant requests to Django and also serve the static files (including CSS).

Comment: ok in that case i will configure an application server and a webserver and check. Thanks